# instantiating angular service in a class (not component)

Tags: angular, angular-services

I'd like to use a service in an Angular class. Just class. This is the code for that:

```
import { EditService } from '../services/edit.service';

export class CustomClass {
   editService:EditService = new EditService();
   constructor(special args here){}
...
}
```

I haven't used one in a class before, and I am used to always passing it in component constructor.

I'm interested if there are any unwanted side effects of using services in such way? Like multiple services of the same type.. Is this a correct way to do it?

Comment: Exactly that: multiple services of the same type. Your `CustomClass` will not be using the same instance that is being provided by DI to other classes in the module. Also you now have to resolve and provide the dependencies of the `EditService` yourself. Why not just use DI?

Comment: I am making instances of Custom class manually. Each instance is a representation of `undo` and `redo` command. It didn't make sense to me to pass editService as an argument, because it contains zero data about the actual redo or undo process. But of course, I need it to trigger the necessary visual effects of redoing or undoing stuff. Perhaps I am overreacting.

Comment: Have you thought about how you will write unit tests doing this? How will you mock behavior if you aren't injecting this behavior into your class?